# Mapping with an AND (&&) relationship in Java

Tags: java, guava, multimap

I was reading about MultiMap in Guava. It says the following relationships can be mapped:

- a → 1, 2
- b → 3

Is it possible to map the following relationships using a map structure in Java/Guava using just POJO?

- a → 1, 2
- b → 3
- c → 3
- d → 4
- c && d → 5
- f → 5

It is the second to last relationship that I am particularly interested in. c alone would give 3. d alone would give 4. c and d together would in this case return 3, 4 and 5.

How could this be achieved?

**UPDATE:** Ideally, I would like in the example I gave searching with a, c and d to give the result 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5. The intention would be for the mapping to be scalable to hundreds of keys, hundreds of values and hundreds of these AND relationships.

I would be expecting to use a Set to search and the result being a Set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the key some value type which takes a list of symbols, e.g. `new AndKey('c')`, `new AndKey('c', 'd')`, representing `c` and `c && d` respectively, and then insert values into the multimap for those keys:

```
ImmutableMultimap<AndKey, Integer> map = ImmutableMultimap.builder()
    .put(new AndKey('c'), 3)
    .put(new AndKey('d'), 4)
    .put(new AndKey('c', 'd'), 3)
    .put(new AndKey('c', 'd'), 4)
    .put(new AndKey('c', 'd'), 5)
    .build();
```

This assumes that you implement `equals` and `hashCode` appropriately in `AndKey` so that two instances with the same symbols are considered equal, e.g.

```
class AndKey {
  private final ImmutableList<Character> symbols;

  AndKey(Character... symbols) { this.symbols = ImmutableList.copyOf(symbols); }

  @Override int hashCode() { return symbols.hashCode(); }
  @Override boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == this) { return true; }
    if (obj instanceof AndKey) { return symbols.equals(((AndKey) obj).symbols); }
    return false;
}
```

or use AutoValue, of course.

Comment: That looks very good. Slightly awkward in that anyone adding to the map would need to take care to add all the combinations by hand. I guess I could write a helper function to calculate these.

Comment: You can also use `Multimap.putAll`, e.g. `putAll(new AndKey('c', 'd'), Arrays.asList(3, 4, 5))`

Comment: Is there an issue here if I search with a, c and d? I would want it to return 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5. In the end, I could need to deal with hundreds of keys, hundreds of values and several of these AND dependent relationships.

Comment: If you searched for `a && c && d` you'd get nothing unless you've explicitly added them. The logic you are trying to implement here isn't particularly clear.

Comment: Sorry that wasn't clear from what I had written. I'll add that to the question.  Your solution would work especially with a helper function calculating every needed additional combination. It could get quite big. An alternative way to implement this would be to have two MultiMaps - one mapping characters to numbers that would in this case add 5 with c or d, then a second mapping numbers to letters that in this case would only have 5 as a key and return c and d - you would then check the original collection had both c and d and delete 5 from the result of the first mapping if it didn't.